# NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied when calling webservice using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm trying to consume a webservice using javascript, but its throwing the following error.
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
This services are successfully consumed on mobile platform.
My code is :

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "http://52.66.119.84:8080/healthcare/rest/user/getAllPlans",
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
username: 'u8@y.com',
password: 'mypassword1',
success: function (data) {
    alert('Success!');
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please read: https://staticapps.org/articles/cross-domain-requests-with-cors/

Comment: @Nehal Thanks Bro